# String arrays does not match

Tags: java, android, arrays

My program displays an array of questions (question one-by-one). After I write an answer, an alert message should tell me whether my answer is right or wrong.
The problem is that, even if I write the right answer the alert message displays a "false" message.

```
final String questions[] = {"Who's Tom?", "Who's Luca?", "Who's Flavie?"}
final String answers[] = {"American", "Italian", "French"}

// display question
answer_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int CurrentQuestionIndex = 0;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        ask_question.setText(question[(CurrentQuestionIndex++) % (questions.length)]);

        // discuss question versus answer
        EditText answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvReponseF);

        if (answer.equals(answers[CurrentQuestionIndex])) {
            alertMessageRight();
        } else {
            alertMessageFalse();
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: Posts your `answers` array.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're comparing an `EditText` object with a `String` field. You must compare `String` with `String` instead.

Here's how to do it:

```
String answer = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvReponseF)).getText().toString();

if(answer.equals(answers[CurrentQuestionIndex]))
{
     ...
```

Comment: that's not all, that's just a minor issue. He's increasing the index counter at the wrong place, check my answer, I covered that also.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the text from the `EditText` object. You are comparing an `EditText` object with a `String`.

So, your complete code should look like this:

```
final String questions[] = {"Who's Tom?", "Who's Luca?", "Who's Flavie?"}
final String answers[] = {"American", "Italian", "French"}

// display question
answer_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
int CurrentQuestionIndex = 0;
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ask_question.setText(question[(CurrentQuestionIndex++) % (questions.length)]);
        // discuss question versus answer
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvReponseF);
        if(editText.getText().toString().equals(answers[CurrentQuestionIndex]))  
        {
            alertMessageRight();
        } else {
            alertMessageFalse();
        }
    } 
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're increasing the index before actually checking if the answer's correct:

```
ask_question.setText(question[(CurrentQuestionIndex++) % (questions.length)]);
```

So the if the question index is 0, you'll get a question 0, then the question index will become 1 because of the `++` operator and you'll be reading the answer 1 instead of 0. I hope you understand this. What you need to do is remove the `++` from here and place it here:

```
if(answer.getText().toString().equals(answers[(CurrentQuestionIndex++) % (questions.length)]))
```

Because at this point, you'll read the proper answer and move on to the next index.

**EDIT**:

This was your biggest problem. Also you need to compare the `answer.getText().toString()` as the other guys already noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
EditText et;//initialize first!!
et.getText().toString().equals(....);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 EditText answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvReponseF);

 if(answer.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals(answers[CurrentQuestionIndex].toLowerCase()))  
{
    alertMessageRight();
} else {
    alertMessageFalse();
}

 }
```

I added the toLowerCase() just make the problem case insensitive.